# Tap recognizer around UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, tap

Good day, I have UIImageView inside UIView and I want to handle event, when user tap on UIView background, but not on UIImageView. How can I achieve it? I read about UITapGestureRecognizer, but it confuse me a little.

P.S. If u can plz answer in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the child view of your main view then you have to enable User Interaction of your `UIImageView` like this

```
imgTest.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

then you have to set the Delegate of your `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detect the `UITouch` of the view, set the delegate like this

```
let touch  = (UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapDetected:"))
touch.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(touch)
```

Then you have to implement the Delegate method of `UITapGestureRecognizer` in which you will detect the view which is currently touched like this

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.valueForKey("view")!.isKindOfClass(UIImageView) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

In the above code i have disable the tap gesture on `UIImageView`

Now, this method will work only for your `self.view` not for `UIImageView`

```
func tapDetected(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line for your imageView because UIImageView default user interaction is disable. If you will enable UIImageView userinteraction then it will not work for your UIView and outside of UIImageView it will work

```
yourImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Try this your tap clicked will work

Comment: I tried, it didn't help.

override func viewDidLoad() {
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapDetected:"))
        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
+
func tapDetected(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: Did you define number of taps and touched required and also enabled User Inter. on the view you want to be touchable ? But basically you should be able to achieve it by (Obj-C - Sorry no swift, but should give you the main idea) 
`UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[_view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];`